# Pseudo-3D Computer Graphics in PHP

Tags: php, 3d

What I'm asking here is if what I have thought up can be done. It sounds feasible, but my attempts so far have been fruitless.

What I want to do is to create an animation of a rotating 3D cube using just PHP. After discovering the imagefilledpolygon function I immediately began to think about creating pseudo-3D shapes, and my new idea revolves around a page switching between multiple frames of a rotating cube to make it look like it's spinning.

Below are two (albeit crude) frames of said cube, but it doesn't switch between the two images at all. It just loads the image under the else, as the session variable hasn't been set yet and stays like that.

```
session_start();

while($toggle=1)
{
if(isset($_SESSION['switch']))
{
    $image = imagecreatetruecolor(2000,1000);
    $col_poly = imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,200);
    $col_poly2 = imagecolorallocate($image,0,200,0);
    imagefilledpolygon($image,array(
        125,0,
        375,0,
        375,250,
        125,250,
        ),
        4 ,
        $col_poly);
    imagefilledpolygon($image,array(
        125,250,
        375,250,
        375,500,
        125,500,
        ),
        4 ,
        $col_poly2);
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        imagepng($image);
        imagedestroy($image);

    unset($_SESSION['switch']);
    sleep(5);
}
else
{
    $image = imagecreatetruecolor(2000,1000);
    $col_poly = imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,200);
    $col_poly2 = imagecolorallocate($image,0,200,0);
    $col_poly3 = imagecolorallocate($image,200,0,0);
    imagefilledpolygon($image,array(
        0,125,
        250,0,
        500,125,
        250,250,
        ),
        4 ,
        $col_poly);
    imagefilledpolygon($image,array(
        250,250,
        0,125,
        0,375,
        250,500,
        ),
        4 ,
        $col_poly2);
    imagefilledpolygon($image,array(
        250,250,
        500,125,
        500,375,
        250,500,
        ),
        4 ,
        $col_poly3);

    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($image);
    imagedestroy($image);

    $_SESSION['switch'] = 1;
    sleep(5);
}
}
```

Just to clarify, I am not interested in any form of CSS animation or however else this can be done. I'm just curious as to if my method would work, that's all.

Could anyone tell me how to echo out text or a button on the page alongside the image as well? Would I actually have to save the polygon image as a png and echo that out separately alongside the text?

Comment: PHP is code that runs on the *server*, animation is something that's done on the *client* so no, your scheme won't work - you would need a program running on the browser (e.g. Javascript) to switch between the images.